# Coregister polygon with shifted coordinates and GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, geojson, software-recommendations, coregistration

I have the polygon boundaries of a lot of buildings in GeoJSON as a Polygon:

[image]

and I also have some GeoTIFF raster of the height of every pixel in that region:
[image]

The problem is that some of the polygons are ok, but some of them are shifted and there is not a consistent direction or magnitude of the shift.

[image]

As you can see, the polygon does not match the raster.

Is there a way to make them match? I've seen some ways to register and coregister rasters but I can't make them work for my case. I've thought also of doing this with computer vision, trying to match the shape, finding its location and then shifting the polygon, but I think this wont be a robust approach.
In this example I've shown an isolated building but in a lot of cases the buildings are attached like this:

[image]

My objective is to align the polygon with its corresponding position in the raster. I want to find a process I could do automatically in thousands of cases like this, I'm open to every type of solution but I'd prefer something consistent and fast.

Comment: It’s not very clear whether you are looking for an out-of-the-box software recommendation (for which there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange) or a coding solution but you have a [tag:python] tag so it seems to be the latter.

Comment: I am looking for anything I could use to process thousands of cases like these. I use python and some tools for all the pipeline but I am looking for anything that could solve this step. Maybe the python tag is not the best one here, just used it because I tried with AROSICS library and OpenCV for the CV approach but I am open to anything